# how to use response of $http.get in other place

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the `reponse.data` (**JSON** data) of `$http.get` in another place of the same `controller` but when try :

```
            $http({
                method:"post",
                url:"php/home/item.php/?proc=3",
                data:{
                    'item_id':json[i].item_id
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;    // or $rootScope
                $scope.data = response.data;
                console.log("after get response : "+$scope.data.length);
            });
            console.log("befor get response : "+$scope.data.length); //  undefined
```

How can I **defer** some instructions to after getting the `response` of `$http.get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you pass to `then` *is the way* you defer execution until after the response has been received. This isn't just a scope or location-in-the-code issue, it's a timing issue. You can call other functions from within that response function, and pass the response along -- that's the only way you can access the response from elsewhere in your controller and be certain that you're executing the code after the response has been received.